# Cast function in sql error

Tags: php, sql, casting

I have this code

> SELECT CAST(i_terminal_id AS INT);

but I can't get it running it always says I have an error near INT. Please help.

**EDIT**

here's my php code.

```
public function selectTerminals($id){
    $form = $this->getUserData();
    $form['id'] = $id;

    $DAO = $this->getDAO('DAO');
    $result=$DAO->query('selectTerminals',$form);
    $y = sizeof($result);


        //$result = terminal ids selected

    $ids = join(',',$result); // 
    $form['terminal_id'] = $ids;
    $form['array_count'] = $y;
    $DAO = $this->getDAO('DAO');
    $result1 = $DAO->query('displayTerminals',$form);
    $sample = sizeof($ids);

    echo $result1;

}
```

Comment: What RDMS are you using? mysql, mssql, oracel etc?

Comment: Where's the rest of the query?  `i_terminal_id` has to come from somewhere.  I think you're missing a `FROM` clause.

Comment: i_terminal_id is an input. The value of it is from my php code.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the semicolon (`;`).
It should be:
`SELECT CAST(i_terminal_id AS INT)`
(assuming the rest of the query, i.e. `FROM` `WHERE` clauses,  is valid...)

**EDIT:**
As per @Arion's comment, this assumes you are using MS-SQL

Comment: If the OP is not using mysql? Right? Do you know that he do not us mysql?

Comment: but my i_terminal_id is an input. the value is coming from my php code which is now stated in my question above.

Answer (score 0):

It needs to be like this:

```
SELECT CAST(i_terminal_id AS INT) FROM Table
```

Comment: But the value of my i_terminal_id is only passed from my php code. It's an input. I didn't get the value from the database

Comment: @maecym So can you give us the possible values in that input parameter.?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT CAST(i_terminal_id AS INT) FROM DUAL
```

In **Oracle/PLSQL**,

> the CAST function converts one datatype to another.

The syntax for the CAST function is:

> CAST ( { expr | ( subquery ) | MULTISET ( subquery ) } AS type_name )

```
select CAST( '22-Aug-2003' AS varchar2(30) ) from dual;
```

> // This would convert the date (ie: 22-Aug-2003) into a varchar2(30)
>   value.
>
> the CONVERT function converts a string from one character set to
>   another.

The syntax of the CONVERT function is:

> CONVERT( string1 , char_set_to , [ char_set_from ] )

**string1** is the string to be converted.

**char_set_to** is the character set to convert to.

**char_set_from** is the character set to convert from.

for further reference please [visit](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/convert.php)